# How to only keep the largest value per year per customer using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I try to figure out this problem:

I got four columns (customer, product, year, price)

**Now, I want to know the most expensive product per customer per year and drop the rest of their purchase history so that in the end (10 years history) I got a list of 10 products per customer (given that they purchased every year).**

I tried a lot lot of things but cannot get it to work, please help a pandas beginner.

[Example DF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBzXu.png)

[Example Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCKjy.png)

Thanks!

Comment: It would help if you can share a sample of your dataframe and expected output

Comment: Please read [`How to ask a question on Stackoverflow`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Try `df_new = df.loc[df.groupby(['customer', 'year'])['price'].idxmax()]`

Comment: Also useful: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 suggestions:

1-------
Common sorting-grouping

```
result1=df.sort_values(['Customer', 'Price'],ascending=[1,0]).groupby(['Customer', 'Year']).head(10)
```

This looks to fit better with your provided output

2--------
With pandas.pivot_table:

```
import pandas as pd
result2=pd.pivot_table(df, index=['Year', 'Customer', 'Product'], values='Price', aggfunc='max')
```

'result2' is a dataframe, so you can play around and get excactly what you want with some sorting. Let me know if you need any help with that

Comment: Thank you so much! The 2nd suggestion did it for me!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a `groupby`:

```
result = (
    df.sort_values(['Year', 'Customer', 'Price'], ascending=[True, True, False])
      .groupby(['Year', 'Customer'])
      .head(1)
)
```